# SQL update to auto-increment column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a test database. I have a bunch of columns and I want to 'purge' the sensitive information so that I can work on it.

```
id   email
1    email1@no-reply.com
2    email2@no-reply.com
#    email#@no-reply.com
```

basicall I want do do `UPDATE table SET email = "email" + id + "@no-reply.com`

I was going to do this in Python, but thought doing it in SQL would be easier.

Comment: `email = concat( "email", table.id, "@no-reply.com" )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, it'll be:

```
UPDATE table
SET email = CONCAT( "email", id, "@no-reply.com" );
```

I just used it on my own table `late` of mysql. Here is the result:

```
mysql> update late
    -> set msg = concat( id, " ", msg );
Query OK, 74397 rows affected (4.15 sec)
Rows matched: 74397  Changed: 74397  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using update you should already have the id. If it was php it would look like:

```
$query = 'Update email set email="email'.$id.'@no-reply.com where email.id='.$id;
```

Where `$query` is the query string you are building and `$id` is the record id you are using to reference the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

For the single-table syntax, the **UPDATE** statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with new values. The **SET** clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given. Each value can be given as an expression, or the keyword **DEFAULT** to set a column explicitly to its default value. The **WHERE** clause, if given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update. With **no WHERE** clause, all rows are updated. If the **ORDER BY** clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The **LIMIT** clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.